# Pandas ValueError when attempting to select data using a boolean operator

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use this code to create a new `Pandas` `DataFrame` consisting of rows where both of my columns of interest have values.

```
sve2_hz = sve2_all[[(sve2_all[' Q l/s'].notnull()) & (sve2_all['Flow_mm/day'].notnull())]]
```

I've also tried changing removing the inner brackets:

```
sve2_hz = sve2_all[[sve2_all[' Q l/s'].notnull() & sve2_all['Flow_mm/day'].notnull()]]
```

However, `Pandas` throws up the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-110-0f3ba1c28b18> in <module>()
----> 1 sve2_hz = sve2_all[[(sve2_all[' Q l/s'].notnull()) & (sve2_all['Flow_mm/day'].notnull())]]
      2 print sve2_hz.head()

C:\Users\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
   1650         if isinstance(key, (Series, np.ndarray, list)):
   1651             # either boolean or fancy integer index
-> 1652             return self._getitem_array(key)
   1653         elif isinstance(key, DataFrame):
   1654             return self._getitem_frame(key)

C:\Users\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in _getitem_array(self, key)
   1687             elif len(key) != len(self.index):
   1688                 raise ValueError('Item wrong length %d instead of %d.' %
-> 1689                                  (len(key), len(self.index)))
   1690             # _check_bool_indexer will throw exception if Series key cannot
   1691             # be reindexed to match DataFrame rows

ValueError: Item wrong length 1 instead of 16636.
```

Could somebody explain what the error message means? In particular the comment "Series key cannot be reindexed to match DataFrame rows".

Comment: could you try removing the inner square braces:`sve2_all[(sve2_all[' Q l/s'].notnull()) & (sve2_all['Flow_mm/day'].notnull())]`

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion works. I'd tried that originally but it returned an empty `DataFrame` so I'd assumed I'd made a mistake. Further investigation reveal that the problem is with my index, it's non-unique and non-monotonic so there were no matches.

Comment: Glad I helped not worth an answer I feel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution as proposed by @EdChum was to remove the inner set of brackets:

```
sve2_all[(sve2_all[' Q l/s'].notnull()) & (sve2_all['Flow_mm/day'].notnull())]
```